# Automating numbering in MS Word 13

Tags: ms-word

Is there any way to automate numbering in MS Word 13?

I have a huge table and I have to change the number sequence according to rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the table cells that you want to autonumber, go to **Home** tab and click the **Numbering** in **Paragraph** group

Here is instruction how to do it:

https://support.office.com/en-my/article/Number-the-cells-in-a-table-a71b7d7b-ee2d-4a4f-9b8b-d971756c1b39